# How do compilers manage their memory footprint?

Tags: compiler-construction, theory

Compilers are able to compile huge quantities of source code. This giant code is translated in AST during the compilation phase. 
I imagine that if the code is huge, this AST will become huge as well.

Can we assume that the compiler will never run out of memory on modern computer by building the AST and keeping it in memory ?

Comment: Most source files are small.

Comment: Linkers don't need a lot of memory. Compilers do, but they can be split into passes.

Comment: @melpomene You'd be surprised. I used to have a compiler (Watcom) that printed the number of lines compiled, and it was typically a few hundred for the .c or .cpp file and many thousands for the .h/.hpp files.

Comment: A modern computer has gigabytes of RAM. Even if each byte of source code generates a separate AST node with over 1000 bytes of overhead (completely unrealistic), you could still fit the AST of a multi-megabyte source file in RAM. When was the last time you saw a source file that's a megabyte large? The largest I ever saw is `X86ISelLowering.cpp` from LLVM:  about 1.2 MB or 32 thousand lines of code, plus whatever the `#include`s expand to, and that's a truly *extreme* example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With virtual memory, the compiler/linker tools don't really have to worry much about memory footprint.

The tool requests what it needs, and the OS either provides enough in a process address space as virtual memory, or [policy decision for particular machine] the OS refuses the tool's request to grow the space at some point, and the process gets an error and typically quits.

Of course, you may have a system with a huge VM limit and not enough physical memory to support it.   Then the tool will page-thrash until it succeeds or the operator stops it in disgust.

[We have our own compiler that we often use to compile a several million line monolithic program.  That compiler typically wants several hundred megabytes of VM to process that program.  This is easily provided by most modern PCs.]

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the memory requirements of compilers usually grow with the input size.

Compilers are no different than any other program whose memory requirement depends on the input size: You just assume that there is enough, and die gracefully otherwise.

Sounds too easy? Well, you can't fight against math. If one really needs that memory, there is either enough or you're out of luck. It's that simple.